# What is the best configuration for a Triple System?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, unix

i'm a new Mac user. Just bought a MacBook Pro 13' .
So i want to use all 3 Systems ( Ubuntu , MacOS , Win7 ) on my Machine.

I Thought about using Boot Camp for Windows and a Virtual Machine ( which one ?! ) for 
Ubuntu.

**Can you give me any advice on that ?**
I'm really new to MacOS, so every little advice is appreciated !

Comment: Is there a reason to have all 3 OSs? or is it just that ur more comfortable with win/ubuntu and u want them there to? in that case i suggest u emerse urself in mac os, u'll get used to it quicker

Comment: Well, i'm a developer and there always situations, where you can only operate in one of these OSs.

Comment: tbh unless your working with Java I don't think you'll encounter a need for linux that can't be satisfied with mac os

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a new Mac (presumably one that uses an Intel i5 or better processor), I think the hassle of rebooting to use BootCamp outweighs the benefit. I would run both Ubuntu and your favorite flavor of Windows in one of the Virtual Machine products. Some prefer [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) because it is free. I'm not in that camp, and I think it has poorer performance than the competing solutions. That leaves [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) or [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html). I've used both, and find little difference between them in real-world usage. I use VMWare Fusion, myself. I would purchase whichever one you can find at a discount. I note that you can often find Parallels included in the Mac software bundle deals that pop up several times a year.

Answer (score 0):

Lion creates a recovery partition at the beginning of your boot disk.  this then pushes your normal OS to partition 2 at least.  Bootcamp can only start Windows if it's partition number is less than 4.  Therefore you only have 2 places to put the bootcamp partition.  I don't know about installing Linux, but if this is also done via the bootcamp mechanism, then your partitions would be 1: Recovery, 2: Mac, 3: Bootcamp 1, 4: Bootcamp 2 - and the last one would not be bootable, so you may want to consider running it in VirtualBox, which is a free Vm machine from Sun which is OK for Linux installs (less good for Windows).